# Bypass reCAPTCHA from a specified origin

Tags: recaptcha

We have a page on our site that uses Google's reCAPTCHA before allowing the user to download a file.
It works great and we totally stopped all the evil bots from spamming our servers.
Now we want to allow a specific entity (user, domain, whatever) to be able to automatically download files without solving the challenge. Or maybe solving it once per session (which will be longer than 2 minutes) and not once per file.

Is there some way we can issue them a multi-use token or have them get a token from Google that will allow them (temporary?) unfettered access to our file downloads? <s>Can we whitelist their domain in the Google admin settings?</s>
Or is this something I need to build myself?

EDIT: It turns I didn't get all the requirements for this assignment. Whitelisting will not satisfy the requirements since it is apparently multiple entities, and that will indubitably change in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reCAPTCHA does not provide specific whitelisting for users or domains.

Instead, you should be looking at making this dynamic on your side. For example, disable reCAPTCHA for signed-in users or generate a token on your server with an expiry time, set that as a cookie on the client, and disable reCAPTCHA for valid tokens.